# C++ compiler discrepency on AVR?

Tags: python, c++, avr-gcc

I am querying an ADC chip via Nanpy running on and Atmega32A chip, and am running into a very curious problem related to function naming. Nanpy is a firmware library that binds Python functions to the same firmware functions. The Python/C++ binding does not seem to be the problem, but rather something in the compiled firmware. Here are some variations on the Nanpy bindings in the C++ firmware:

```
// these work:
if (strcmp(m->getName(), "getOffsetRegister2") == 0) m->returns(v[m->getObjectId()]->getOffsetRegister2());    
if (strcmp(m->getName(), "getOffsetRegister3") == 0) m->returns(v[m->getObjectId()]->getOffsetRegister());    
if (strcmp(m->getName(), "getOffsetRegister") == 0) m->returns(v[m->getObjectId()]->getOffsetRegister2());  

// this statement fails to return
if (strcmp(m->getName(), "getOffsetRegister") == 0) m->returns(v[m->getObjectId()]->getOffsetRegister());
```

Both getOffsetRegister and getOffsetRegister2 are identical functions.

Based on these variations, I can call either getOffsetRegister or getOffsetRegister2 from a python function with a name other than getOffsetRegister. I can also call getOffsetRegister2 from the python function getOffsetRegister, but when I call getOffsetRegister from the same name python function it fails to return.

So, is this a C++ compiler error or am I missing something? I want to track down the cause of the problem if it is not a compiler error in order to prevent the same problem happening again if possible.

Comment: What is `v`?  Is it the `strcmp` that fails to return, or something from the following statement?

Comment: I believe it is the array of drivers/adapters for hardware supported by Nanpy. In this case, it would be my driver for the ADC chip of which getOffsetRegister() and getOffsetRegister2() are both defined and are identical except the name.

Answer (score 0):

While not really an answer, it appears that the problem was resolved by changing the set of 'ifs' to an 'if else if' set of clauses:

```
if (strcmp(m->getName(), "getOffsetRegister2") == 0) m->returns(v[m->getObjectId()]->getOffsetRegister2());    
else if (strcmp(m->getName(), "getOffsetRegister3") == 0) m->returns(v[m->getObjectId()]->getOffsetRegister());    
else if (strcmp(m->getName(), "getOffsetRegister") == 0) m->returns(v[m->getObjectId()]->getOffsetRegister2());  

// this statement works now
else if (strcmp(m->getName(), "getOffsetRegister") == 0) m->returns(v[m->getObjectId()]->getOffsetRegister());  
else {
    // return some kind of error
}
```

In further testing, I found that the original code also failed for some additional if statements as well. When 'else' was added, all the failed comparisons worked. Perhaps too many if comparisons is not the best practice.